# Using "CAST" operator in sql with where and IN clause not working

Tags: sql-server

The right query that works fine is

```
 select * from Pretty_Txns where Send_Customer in   ('1000000000164774783','1000000000253252111')
```

But I have data coming from outside SQL from a python application which is of the below format and of a varying length and hence the use of **IN** clause as it can be easily parameterised

```
  (1000000000164774783,1000000000253252111)
```

So , I am trying to use a **CAST** operator to make life simple

```
    select  * from Pretty_Txns where cast (Send_Customer as numeric) in(1000000000164774783,1000000000253252111)
```

But it fails with:

```
    Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

    select  * from Pretty_Txns where cast (Send_Customer as bigint) in(1000000000164774783,1000000000253252111) 

    Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
```

Comment: what's `Send_Customer` current data type?, does it have only numeric values?, what's the biggest number that's stored?

Comment: Send_Customer datatype is varchar  and yes only numeric values but datatype is varchar and cannot be changed

Comment: yes, but varchar with what length?, and what's the largest number that can be stored?

Comment: the length is varchar(50)

Comment: can you please answer what's the largest number that can be stored in `Send_Customer`?, it's the third time I'm asking

Comment: What version of SQL Server too? What does `select  * from Pretty_Txns where try_cast (Send_Customer as numeric(38,0)) is null and Send_Customer  is not null` return?

Comment: @Lamak there are just way too many Send_Customer to determine the largest number. but length is varchar(50). So a string with 50 chars.

Comment: @MartinSmith sql server 2010

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2010 so `try_cast` may or may not exist dependent on what version you are really on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  * from Pretty_Txns where cast (Send_Customer as numeric(38)) in(1000000000164774783,1000000000253252111) --default total digits is 18 if not specified
```

or

```
select  * from Pretty_Txns where cast (Send_Customer as bigint) in(1000000000164774783,1000000000253252111)
```

Updated:
First to check whether there are all numeric types of records in Send_Customer

This will give you all the records that contain only numbers,

```
SELECT Send_Customer FROM yourTable WHERE Send_Customer NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%
```

or you could run the following two to compare:

1:

```
select Count(*) 
from (
SELECT Send_Customer 
FROM yourTable
WHERE Send_Customer  NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
) as ABC
```

2:

```
select count(Send_Customer) 
        from yourtable
```

Compare the result number with the total you have in table, if does not match, there must be some containing non numeric characters, then it cannot do the convert from varchar(..)(I assume it is varchar here) to numeric, unless you have take care of those records first, such as replace other characters, delete other characters using `REPLACE` or `STUFF`, but it will bring the data loss, which may not be accurate in your case.

Comment: some of the `Send_Customer` in your table exceed the default precision

Comment: Still fails with Error converting data type varchar to numeric. . And already tried with bigint. Same error

Comment: any special character? or just pure numbers?

Comment: Most are pure numbers but it is a huge transaction database and there may be some with special characters

Comment: then it will fail converting from string (varchar, nvarchar, char, nchar) to any number type (int, smallint, bigint....)

Comment: Run this to see whether it is the case:SELECT Send_Customer 
FROM yourTable
WHERE Send_Customer  NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%', if it returns anything, then you cannot convert

Comment: the 1st one without any problem is because you are comparing string with string, but second one failed because you are string to convert any non-numeric string to numeric, it will fail no matter it is implicitly or explicitly convert.

Comment: That tries to  pulls out all send_customers . In fact all. And they are all with numbers

Comment: Sp , there is no way to do this in SQL? Has to be done outside it?

Comment: the query I gave to you is to get all the pure numeric records,  compare the number of return with the total, if it does not match, that means there are some containing not only numbers, even english characters

Comment: You have to treat those non numeric records first, it depends on your real case, any operation against deleting, replacing, etc will make your result not accurate

Comment: Agreed..thanks for your help. I think it will be much easier to deal with this at python level. The size of the table is just too large to run count(Send_Customer) queries. Still running it though. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could also cast the individual values in the `IN` clause to `varchar` if there were only a few, instead of casting the DB field. That way, you wouldn't get a conversion error if `send_customer` contained some non-numeric data.

Just adding this in case anyone else comes across it in Google.